# How to read console-output-text by an eclipse-plugin?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I'm trying to write an Eclipse plugin which starts a `LaunchConfiguration` when an already running `LaunchConfiguration` prints a user-predefined-string in the console.

Here is a pseudocode example for what I'm looking for:

```
            String check = "Server started and running";

            new ConsoleOutputListener(Event event) {
            String consoleText = event.getConsoleOutputTextOfAllConsoles();

                if(consoleText.contains(check)) {
                    //launch LaunchConfiguration 
                }

            }
```

Is there a way to implement the example from above? 
Any help si appreciated as always!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You question is a bit unclear as to what exactly you want to do, but possibly you can use the `org.eclipse.ui.console.consolePatternMatchListeners` extension point to define a pattern match listener on a console.

Something like (from the Eclipse help):

```xml
<extension
     point="org.eclipse.ui.console.consolePatternMatchListeners">
  <consolePatternMatchListener
        class="com.example.ExampleConsolePatternMatcher"
        id="com.example.ExampleConsolePatternMatcher"
        regex=".*foo.*">
     <enablement>
        <test property="org.eclipse.ui.console.consoleTypeTest" value="exampleConsole"/>
     </enablement>
  </consolePatternMatchListener>
</extension>
```

Which matches a regular expression on a particular type of console.

The console support has many extension points for defining different types of extension to the consoles.

If you want to do this more dynamically you can listen for consoles being created using the `IConsoleManager`:

```java
IConsoleManager manager = ConsolePlugin.getDefault().getConsoleManager(); 

// Existing consoles
IConsole[] consoles = manager.getConsoles();

// Listen for consoles being added/removed
manager.addConsoleListener(console listener);
```

Text consoles will be an instance of `TextConsole` you can add a pattern listener using the `TextConsole` `addPatternMatchListener` method.

Comment: Hello Greg I edited the question and added an example. I think your solution is not what I'm specifically looking for, but maybe you can take a look at the edited question again. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you will still have to use pattern matcher listeners but you can set this up dynamically by listening for consoles being added. I have updated the answer to have an outline of how to do that.

Comment: It works perfectly. Thank you Greg for your great work here at Stackoverflow.